# Is it possible to set the window size of multiple different tkinter frames?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a GUI where I need different tkinter frames to have different window sizes due to what is contained within them. Is there a way to explicitly set the size of these frames, or size them relative to what is contained within them?

Comment: One of the ways is using `.place()` on the frames, then you can use `width=...` and `height=...` to specify the required size, or `relwidth=...` and `relheight=...` to specify the size relative to the parent container.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple ways. The best way is to let the frames auto-size to fit their contents. If you make the contents the size you want, the frames will grow or shrink to an appropriate size. Explicitly setting a frame size is rarely the right choice if you want to create a responsive, efficiently laid-out window.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Kane_Iskra there are two main ways of doing what you want.

1. By using the right frame placement method
2. By resizing the window

To relatively place an item inside a frame you have to use a pack or grid method of placement. For example.

Pack

```
frame1 = tk.frame(root, width=30,height=30)
frame1.pack(side='top')
```

Grid

```
frame1 = tk.frame(root, width=30,height=30)
frame1.grid(row='top')

# set weights to the frame so when you resize the window the frame size changes
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Or you can also change the size of the window by using

```
root.geometry('1000x540')
```

Comment: I forgot to specify this is within a class, with each class being a frame. How would this work in that case. I do appreciate the help though, it has clarified setting the height without classes.

Comment: Make sure that your class __init__ functions looks like this.
``` class MyFrameClass(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
```

then you can do MyFrameClass(width=30,height=30)

Answer (score 0):

I once did the example with classes because you wrote in the text above my post that you were looking for such an example.

If you want to change your windows dynamically, `place` is a very good option (`grid` is also possible, of course). The disadvantage of this is that if you change one size, you mostly have to change it for another frame (but it is not always the case). And you have to constantly experiment with the numbers of `rely, relx` ....

```
from tkinter import *


class MainWindow(Tk):   
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()

        self.parent = parent

    #=> your class imports:
        # toolbar:
        self.toolBar = ToolBar(self)    
        self.toolBar.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
        
        # main
        self.main = Main(self)
        self.main.place(relx=0, rely=0.1, relwidth=1, relheight=0.9)


class ToolBar(Frame):          
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, bg="light blue") # you can set your frame attributes here

        self.parent = parent    # your reference to the other classes, for example (if you
        # want to communicate with class Main: self.parent.main.widget.....)


class Main(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, bg="light green", highlightthickness=10) # frame attributes

        self.parent = parent    # reference

        btn = Button(self, text="CloseApp", bg=self.cget("bg"), command=self.parent.destroy)    #exit button
        btn.place(relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.3, rely=0.35, relx=0.35)    # self.parent.destroy reference to you MainWindow (to destroy)


if __name__ == '__main__':  
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.geometry("750x500")
    mw.mainloop()
```

Comment: my frames are dynamic, so they are being shown one at a time, so they cannot be in relation to each other. Is `place()` still able to work in relation to the tkinter widgets within the frames.